# MySQL - composite primary key or create separate tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

So we have multiple identical devices in the field that record weather data every second. This timestamped data is then aggregated on a remote server. My goal is to store this timestamped data in a MySQL database on the remote server.

Say we have **N** devices - this means we have **N** rows/data lines for the same timestamp. And each device has a unique id.

I'm debating between:

1. one table with **(timestamp,device_id)** as the primary key
2. creating a separate table for each device with **timestamp** as the primary key

Is either a better solution? Is there a **third** way of doing this?

We will be accessing the data as a time series.

Comment: Option #1 hands down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're accessing the data as a time series, you will probably have lots of cases where you want to do aggregation over all your devices. For instance, what's the highest value recorded, what's the average value recorded, etc.

If you store each device's results in a separate table, that would make it a more difficult to do those aggregations. You'd have to UNION all the tables, and every time you added a device with its own new table, you'd have to change your code to include the new table in the UNION.

Whereas if you keep all the data in one table, with a composite key, you can treat the device id as an attribute, and then do aggregations over any number of devices without changing your code.

Anytime I see the word "per" mentioned in a database design, I treat it as a red flag, with a high probability that it indicates trouble.

E.g. *"a table per measurement device"* or *"a column per monthly sales results".*

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 hands down: one table with (timestamp,device_id) as the primary key.

Managing multiple tables, one per device, will become a nightmare quite quickly. It may seem like a good idea at first, but you would need to use a lot of dynamic SQL for every single data storing or retrieval; this is a lot of work to implement, and a lot of work to debug and ensure quality. It's a flaky solution if you don't have a lot of resources (people) for testing it.

On the other hand, MySQL's engine is quite good at storing and retrieving data for separate devices in the same table. To improve performance it's just a matter of setting up the right indexes and the queries should run well. The persistence will be easy and fast to implement, and you'll avoid a lot of simple errors. Not to mention the cases when you need to get stats across all the devices, not just a single one. This is easily solvable with a single table; with multiple ones, it would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

One table!  Do NOT design your database so you must create a new table for each device.

Why one table?  It will handle any number of devices transparently.  Properly indexed it will perform reasonably well at scale.

Why avoid a table per device? Tables use scarce operating system resources like file descriptors and RAM. Plus, adding tables to an existing database in production is a hassle, especially if you must remember to index the new ones the same as the old ones.

Your proposal for a composite primary key is just right.

You should also consider adding a `(device_id, timestamp)` compound index in case you need to run time-series operations on individual devices.

You would be wise to read about *covering indexes* as you design your queries.

Comment: Depending on the `SELECTs` that you have, Having `PRIMARY KEY(device_id, timestamp)` may be better than the opposite order.  In any case, you will probably need a secondary index with the opposite ordering.